# How to add global loading/spin effect in axios interceptor for a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, interceptor

I am use axios for API call in a React project, and I want to add a loading or spinning effect globally in between a api call's request and response in my axios interceptor, here is the code of my interceptor.

```
import Axios from 'axios'

Axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // spinning start to show
  const token = window.localStorage.token;
  if (token) {
     config.headers.Authorization = `token ${token}`
  }
  return config
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

Axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // spinning hide
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps you could take a simpler approach, where you display a full-screen loading message while your app is busy loading data via axios?

For example, you could make the following additions to your code/project to show a global "loading message" on screen while during axio requests:

CSS:

```
/* Define css class for global loading message to cover 
   screen during axios operations */

.loading-indicator:before {
    content: '';
    background: #000000cc;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.loading-indicator:after {
    content: 'Loading';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5rem;        
}
```

Javascript:

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

  // spinning start to show
  // UPDATE: Add this code to show global loading indicator
  document.body.classList.add('loading-indicator');

  const token = window.localStorage.token;
  if (token) {
     config.headers.Authorization = `token ${token}`
  }
  return config
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

Axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

  // spinning hide
  // UPDATE: Add this code to hide global loading indicator
  document.body.classList.remove('loading-indicator');

  return response;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Using this method, you could even use CSS3 animations to replace the "loading" message with a animated spinner, or something similar - hope this helps!

Comment: in which file should i put it for global access ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: in react i should put this code in app.js file or anywhere else I am new to react so please if you can describe because I want to access in each component from single place.

Comment: Just need to import the interceptor file into index.js file. like import './interceptor'

Comment: @DacreDenny What about concurrent requests? Consider 2 requests is sent to server and loader is shown. Then request 1's response hit then loader is gone but response of request 2 not received yet!

Comment: @AliSohrabi yes you make a very good point - my understanding was the OP wanted this loading effect for single calls at a time "between [ a ] api call's" - my solution would need to be extended to reliably allow for concurrent requests

Comment: I have the exactly same scenario with multiple requests and single loading indicator - assuming anything else is bellow useful.

I will apply this approach but will introduce array with the all current requests and only hide the indicator when the array is of length zero.

Another option would be to increment/decrement a number, but that feels a bit clanky.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup *axios* interceptors in a higher level component let's say App. You can define a loading state in the reducer with "SHOW_LOADER" & "HIDE_LOADER" action types. These interceptors will dispatch the corresponding actions before a request is sent and received via *axios*, updating the loading state in store through which you can render a Loader component.

Hope this answers your question.

**App Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loading } from '../actions'
import Loader from './Loader'

class App extends React.Component{
 componentWillMount(){
   const self = this
   axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
     // spinning start to show
     self.props.loading(true)
     return config
    }, function (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
     // spinning hide
      self.props.loading(false)

     return response;
   }, function (error) {
     return Promise.reject(error);
   });
 }
 render(){
   return (
    <div>
      { this.props.loader ? <Loader /> : null }

      {/* 
        Your other components
      */}
    </div>
   )
 }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  return {
    loader: state.loader
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
  loading
})(App);
```

**Loader Reducer**

```
const loader = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SHOW_LOADER":
            return action.data;
            break;
        case "HIDE_LOADER":
            return action.data;
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default loader;
```

**Action**

```
export const loading = (bool)=>{
  return bool ? {
    type:"SHOW_LOADER",
    data:bool
  }: {
    type: "HIDE_LOADER",
    data: bool
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add axios interceptor in this way otherwise it will simply return the config object only.

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
//add loader
dispatch(loadingAction(true));

return config
```

});

Axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

```
//remove loader
dispatch(loadingAction(false));

return response;
```

});