# Intercept all API requests with a Loader Component - React Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I would like to add a Loader component to be rendered whenever an API call is being made in React. I have an isFetching flag in my reducer and now I am able to do it on a component level based on this prop. But I need one globally. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778456/how-to-add-global-loading-spin-effect-in-axios-interceptor-for-a-react-project) I am planning to use.

Below is my dataService:

```
        //if dev mode them URL prefix = http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    //else
    // prefix= .

    // url= prefix + /users/xyz
    import axios from 'axios';

    const DEV_MODE_URL_PREFIX = '/api/';
    const PROD_MODE_URL_PREFIX = './api/';
    const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    function getService(relativeUrl, options) {

        return dataService(relativeUrl, options);
    }

    function postService(relativeUrl, dataToPost, options) {
        return dataService(relativeUrl, options, dataToPost);
    }

    function dataService(relativeUrl, options, dataToPost) {
        /**
         * dataToPost = {
         *  key: value
         * } || string
         * options = {
         *  actions: {
         *    requestAction: function ()
         *    successAction: function (response)
         *    failureAction: function (error)
         *  },
         *  shouldRequest: function (state)
         * }
         */
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            let url;
            const { requestAction, successAction, failureAction } = options.actions;
            if (relativeUrl.match(/json/)) {
                url = relativeUrl;
            } else {
                if (relativeUrl[0] === '/') {
                    relativeUrl = relativeUrl.slice(1);
                }
                if (relativeUrl[relativeUrl.length - 1] !== '/') {
                    relativeUrl += '/';
                }
                if (ENV !== 'production') {
                    url = DEV_MODE_URL_PREFIX + relativeUrl;
                } else {
                    url = PROD_MODE_URL_PREFIX + relativeUrl;
                }
            }

            if (options.shouldRequest(getState())) {
                let promise;
                const data = typeof dataToPost === 'string' ? { 'data': dataToPost } : dataToPost;
                dispatch(requestAction());
                promise = dataToPost ? axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true }) : axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
                return promise
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(
                            `status: ${response.status}
                message: ${response.message}`
                        );
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            return dispatch(successAction(response, dispatch));
                        }
                        return Promise.reject(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        return dispatch(failureAction(error));
                    });
            } else {
                return Promise.reject('FETCHING');
            }
        };
    }

    export {
        getService,
        postService
    };
```

Please advice.

I have earlir done it in [Angular](https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9) and would like the same thing in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup *axios* interceptors in a higher level component let's say App. You can define a loading state in the reducer with "SHOW_LOADER" & "HIDE_LOADER" action types. These interceptors will dispatch the corresponding actions before a request is sent and received via *axios*, updating the loading state in store through which you can render a Loader component.

Hope this answers your question.

**App Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loading } from '../actions'
import Loader from './Loader'

class App extends React.Component{
 componentWillMount(){
   const self = this
   axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
     // spinning start to show
     self.props.loading(true)
     return config
    }, function (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
     // spinning hide
      self.props.loading(false)

     return response;
   }, function (error) {
     return Promise.reject(error);
   });
 }
 render(){
   return (
    <div>
      { this.props.loader ? <Loader /> : null }

      {/* 
        Your other components
      */}
    </div>
   )
 }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  return {
    loader: state.loader
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
  loading
})(App);
```

**Loader Reducer**

```
const loader = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SHOW_LOADER":
            return action.data;
            break;
        case "HIDE_LOADER":
            return action.data;
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default loader;
```

**Action**

```
export const loading = (bool)=>{
  return bool ? {
    type:"SHOW_LOADER",
    data:bool
  }: {
    type: "HIDE_LOADER",
    data: bool
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve the same using the dataService file I have? I am dynamically rendering components based on Route and do not have an App/Parent component. Is it okay to do it in index.js?

Comment: The whole reason for using interceptors is to perform a repeated task at every request response cycle. This should ideally be set up the first thing your app boots. Why would you use it in your dataService file just to do the same thing again which already has been setup up globaly ( maybe in index.js as you said)

Comment: @HemantParashar, how multiple async calls can be handled using this approach? Loader will go on and off for each request.